# Align messages left/right

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I using the firebase API. to send and retrieve messages. However I am having trouble in trying to set layout for the sender/retriever so Messages will align left/right. At the moment I only have one layout which both the sender/retriever is using, but not sure on how to set different layouts.

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageViewHolder> {

    private List<Message> messagesList;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference userDatabaseRef;
    private   FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Context context;
   private String imageUrl;


    public MessageAdapter(List<Message> messagesList) {
        this.messagesList = messagesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Message c = messagesList.get(viewType);
        String sender = c.getFrom();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(sender);

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.messages_layout, parent, false);
            return new MessageViewHolder(v);


    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, final int index) {


        final Message c = messagesList.get(index);

        final String sender = c.getFrom();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(sender);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);

              viewHolder.setUserimage(context,imageUrl);


                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                viewHolder.displayName.setText(name);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }

        });

        viewHolder.messageText.setText(c.getMessage());
        viewHolder.time.setText(EpochtimeToDateAndTimeString(c.getTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messagesList.size();
    }


    public String EpochtimeToDateAndTimeString(long time) {
        Date date = new Date(time);
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        String formatted = format.format(date);
        return formatted;
    }



}
```

> MessageViewHolder

```
public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView messageText;
public TextView displayName;
public TextView time;
public ImageView showImage;

public MessageViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.messagetext);
    displayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
    time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    showImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_post_userimage3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use different view holders for sender's and receiver's messages.

Create two layouts: **R.layout.sender_message_layout** and **R.layout.receiver_message_layout**

Create two viewholders: **SenderMessageHolder** and **ReceiverMessageHolder**.

Define view type integer constants:

```
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SENDER = 1;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVER = 2;
```

Implement [getItemViewType(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) on your adapter:

```
if(messageList.get(position).getFrom().equals(...)) {
    return VIEW_TYPE_SENDER;
} else {
    return VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVER;
}
```

In **onCreateViewHolder()** function check view type and create different holders for different senders:

```
View v;

if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_SENDER) {
    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.sender_message_layout, parent, false);
    return new SenderMessageHolder(v);
} else {
    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.receiver_message_layout, parent, false);
    return new ReceiverMessageHolder(v);
}
```

In onBindViewHolder() check holder instance to bind values to views accordingly:

```
if(holder instanceof SenderMessageHolder) {
    ((SenderMessageHolder) holder).textView.setText(...);
    ...
} else {
    ((ReceiverMessageHolder) holder).textView.setText(...);
    ...
}
```

Hope that it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  The way I would recommend is by overriding the `public int getItemViewType(int position)` for your adapter. You must implement logic here to help you determine the layout file to return and returning a view type constant.

```
public static int INCOMING = 1;
public static int OUTGOING = 2;

    @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) { 
    int viewType = -1;       
    Message m = messagesList.get(position)
    //Logic here determining if m is left or right aligned and  
    // return either 
    // MessageAdapter.OUTGOING OR MessageAdapter.INCOMING
    return viewType;
}
```

Create a left-aligned layout file and a right-aligned layout file. Your new `onCreateviewHolder()` adapter method will look something like this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Message c = messagesList.get(viewType);
    String sender = c.getFrom();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(sender);

    View v;

    if( viewType == MessageAdapter.INCOMING ) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.messages_layout_left, parent, false);
    }else if ( viewType == MessageAdapter.OUTGOING) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.messages_layout_right, parent, false);
    }


    return new MessageViewHolder(v);


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you help me with logic for determining if m is left or right please

Comment: also im not sure where getItemViewtype gets called?

Comment: `getItemViewType` gets called by the adapter. The logic for determining if m is left or right is going to depend on the `Message` object.  From your code above you have `m.getSender()` which you could compare to the current user? Maybe something like:  `return m.getSender().equals(currentUser.name()) ? INCOMING : OUTGOING;`

Comment: You don't explicitly call getViewType() as it's result is passed into the createViewHolder method as the 2nd parameter